# Mounting Shared VirtualBox Folder Over User Directory

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount

I am using VirtualBox for some development work where I ocassionally need to delete the machine and start over (due to bad config or install, etc.). I have my data mounted as VirtualBox shared folders under the usual `/media/sf_shared` directory. This works ok most of the time but often I end up losing small files, settings and configurations that get saved to the user folder under `~`. I'd like to copy my user folder over to shared (something like `/media/sf_shared/user`) and then mount that over the `/home/user` folder so that changes to the user folder automatically get saved to the shared folder on my system.

I've tried:

- bind mounts but the system becomes unstable when doing this (especially with making changes to the Desktop folder).
- deleting the user folder and symlinking over it `ln -s /media/sf_shared/user /home/user`. This causes instability as well and I am unable to log in after a system reboot.
- changing the users home directory to `/media/sf_shared/user` but this also causes me to be unable to log in
- OverlayFS, which simply tells me that the filesystem isn't supported (looking at the filesystem of `/media/sf_shared/user` using `df .`, I see the filesystem is called `shared`, which is probably what is preventing OverlayFS from working correctly.

Is there a good solution for mounting a shared VirtualBox folder over my users home folder, so that all changes to the home folder get saved to my shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would try mounting a separate shared folder to /home instead of /media/sf_shared. The idea is to mount the folder at startup (as root) so that it is already available during login. Mounting the home folder on a separate drive was common practice for multi-user *nix machines (as opposed to single user machines like typical Ubuntu installs these days).

How you do this depends on the distro, but basically you need to use the mount command after the Shared Folders service is started. Put the mount command in /etc/rc.local for Debian distros. This should work as long as the distro/version doesn't change when you rebuild again.

[Here's more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)

Comment: Could you expand a little- how and why?